# How do I edit the fields created_at and updated_at in Django admin?

Tags: django

I am creating a model in the back end but I do not see the fields created_at and updated at so I can specify a date (today) that I created the model. So now on the front end it displays a NAN for the date?

I tried adding the fields manually using a fieldset but I get the following error:

```
'created_at' cannot be specified for Project model form as it is a non-editable field. Check fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class ProjectAdmin.
```

Why can someone not edit the dates for those fields? Why are they read_only? So creating objects in the admin in futile?

Answer (score 0):

well, the created_at and updated_at are timestamps, which are created to track the changes made to the table. And naturally, it is not editable so as to maintain the consistency of the data table.

But, it can be shown on the client side, by using the form field though.
There might be some issue with your frontend, for not rendering the same.
More over, check the format of the date on the client side.

If you are still unable to get the issue solved, please share your code. I'll try to help you out.

Comment: So how do you have a model with dates that you want to be able to change like for instance an Ad model that has a start and end date? Why can I not edit any dates in Django admin?

Comment: It's because the fields contain auto_add_now or auto_now that is why you cannot edit those fields. If you leave those keyword arguments out the field becomes editable.

Comment: Yeah, If you remove those attributes, the fields can be come editable. But, than it basically obsolete the reason why, created_at and updated_at is being used right? if it's some date field you can surely be able to change it using the forms field.